# Ethjs-contract package providing transaction related error when calling get function

Tags: contract-development, ether, metamask

I am integrating MetaMascara to my lottery DApp.
**HTML**

```
<script src="https://wallet.metamask.io/metamascara.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/ethjs-query.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/ethjs-contract.min.js"></script>
```

**Javascript**

```
  const ethereumProvider = metamask.createDefaultProvider()
  ethQuery = new Eth(ethereumProvider);
  CONTRACT = new EthContract(ethQuery);
  contract = CONTRACT(contractAbi, contractByteCode, {from: window.METAMASK_ACCOUNT, gas: 300000});
  contractInstance = contract.at(contractAddress);
  const accounts = await ethQuery.accounts();
  window.METAMASK_ACCOUNT = accounts[0] || 'locked'
```

Here's success script(when getting a variable defined in contract).

```
  contractInstance.threshold();// success providing correct threshold
```

Here's error script(when calling a contract function, that is not transaction related)

```
  contractInstance.Function1(startTicketToSync);
```

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload
>   {"id":6135743116650,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":[{"gas":"0x493e0","to":"0x9b7e002a05efebe6e6c4fb8d15c9203dfc1e605f","data":"0xdb493a6b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"}],"method":"eth_sendTransaction"}
>   {"message":"Undefined address - from address required to sign
>   transaction.","code":-32603}

When I call the function in Metamask extension available space it is providing appropriate information.(using web3)

```
  contract = web3.eth.contract(contractAbi);
  contractInstance = contract.at(contractAddress);
  contractInstance.Function1.call(startTicketToSync, callback);
```

Smart contract solidity script

```
contract Contract1 is Ownable {
    uint public threshold;
    ...
    function Function1(uint start) public returns (uint, uint, uint, bool ) {
       require(start >= 1 && start <= currentTicket);
        uint i;
        for (i = start; i <= currentTicket; i++) {
            if (tickets[i].holder == msg.sender && tickets[i].winAmt > 0) {
                return (i, tickets[i].ref, tickets[i].winAmt, tickets[i].paid);
            }
        }
        return (currentTicket + 100, 0, 0, false);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue, after 3 days brainstorming, but the error string is making the developers hard to find issue.

I have fixed this.

```
  const ethereumProvider = metamask.createDefaultProvider()
  ethQuery = new Eth(ethereumProvider);
  CONTRACT = new EthContract(ethQuery);
  contract = CONTRACT(contractAbi, contractByteCode, {from: window.METAMASK_ACCOUNT, gas: 300000});
  contractInstance = contract.at(contractAddress);
  const accounts = await ethQuery.accounts();
  window.METAMASK_ACCOUNT = accounts[0] || 'locked'
```

TO

```
  const ethereumProvider = metamask.createDefaultProvider()
  ethQuery = new Eth(ethereumProvider);
  CONTRACT = new EthContract(ethQuery);
  const accounts = await ethQuery.accounts();
  window.METAMASK_ACCOUNT = accounts[0] || 'locked'
  contract = CONTRACT(contractAbi, contractByteCode, {from: window.METAMASK_ACCOUNT, gas: 300000});
  contractInstance = contract.at(contractAddress);
```

Changed the order.
The error was because smart contract function was calling `msg.sender`, and when I set to origin, contract call address is default become `undefined`.

It took 3 days for me to fix( **suddenly I got answer when posting to this platform**), and hope this experience helps others solve this in 1min!